# Adding a video into a fragment but app crashes when launched on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, crash, android-videoview

I've been backtracking everything I do up until I add the code for the video and the app works fine But when I add the code for the video I want to play on fragment 3, the app crashes. I'm getting no errors at all when building.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kgeu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlnLh.png)

[Activity Main_P1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVKzb.png)

[Activity Main_P2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11F4y.png)

Comment: Please, show log crash

Comment: Uploaded it there, I assume the error is being caused by:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.golden_goat2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)

Comment: Can you please show the xml file "activity_main"?

Comment: Added it there, sorry for the wait.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your VideoView by XML id as follows.

Replace

```
VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
```

with

```
VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.app_promo);
```

Hope so this helps you.